# how to publish a visual studio project 2008 that uses text files?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have created my setup.exe and it runs successfully, but I can´t access to my .txt files.

how can I publish the project including these .txt files?

FileOpen(1, "xls.txt", OpenMode.Input) <--- what should my filename be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

your text file should be in the root directory i.e. where setup.exe is located

Comment: Thanks, you´re right, but I want Visual Studio to automatically copy the files there when the application is installed.

Comment: include the text file in your solution before you publish

Comment: I don´t know exactly how to do that, do I have to include it as a resource?

Comment: check this out. seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119533/how-to-copy-a-file-thats-in-the-same-directory-as-the-installer

Comment: I liked the idea, but it´s for c# and I don´t know how to get the SourceDir  in VB